# How do I add a predefined class to a custom html element?

Tags: php, customization

I have a basic loop within **single.php** Also the class **.title_name** within **style.css** hooked up with functions.php i.e all is set and working. My code snippet below:

```
<?php
                    while(have_posts()) {
                        the_post();
                    ?> 
                    <!-- HTML STARTS HERE -->
                    <h2 <?php echo $titleTemplate; ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <!-- HTML ENDS UP HERE -->
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php 
                    if (is_single()) : return $titleTemplate = 'class="title_name"';
                    endif; ?>
```

As far as I am considered I have to write simple IF statement which checks if I am within any post, if true It should return a variable with some class assigned to. After I just do echo within desirable opening tag elment but no result at all. Maybe it's scope issue. I am not very familiar with wordpress coding nor php itself yet so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just write `<h2 class="title_name">`?

Comment: I want to share this .css class as a blueprint styling for each post within single.php. I can do inline as an example: `<h2 <?php if (is_single()) echo 'class="title_name"' ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></h2>` but instead I want something as `<h2 <?php if echo $titleTemplate ?> ><?php the_title(); ?></h2>`. In such case my question would where I have to put my IF statement for $titleTemplate within single.php so to get same result but VIA variable.